# how to sync $scope between a directive and controller in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive as the following:

```
app.directive('fileInput', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('change', function () {
            $parse(attrs.fileInput)
            .assign(scope, element[0].files)
            scope.$apply();
        });
        scope.$watch('files', function () {
            console.log(scope.files);
        });
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $element.bind('change', function () {
            $parse($attrs.fileInput)
            .assign($scope, $element[0].files)

            $scope.$apply();
        });
        $scope.$watch('files', function () {
                console.log($scope.files);
            });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
and this is controller:

```
controllers.controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$http', 'Restangular', 'ServiceRepository', 
function($scope, $routeParams, $location, $http, Restangular, ServiceRepository) 
{
   $scope.regService = function () {
        $scope.error = {};
        $scope.submitted = true;

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("model", angular.toJson($scope.services));

        console.log($scope.files);
   }

}
```

And this is view file

```
<input type="file" id="boarding-picture_where_sleeping" class="form-control" file-input="files" multiple>
```

Additional info, regService() method is called when submitting the form

and when I debug $scope.files, it's available in console tab. but in my controller, it's undefined

so how to sync it between the directive and controller
Thanks

Comment: Try changing controller to link.

Comment: what your `fileInput` attribute contains?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz tried with link function, but unfortunately it's not working. Just updated my question with link function

Comment: @PankajParkar this is fileInput template 
<grooming-sub-service></grooming-sub-service>

Comment: @hoangk could you add directive element to..as you are using `attrs.fileInput` that is expecting some value should be provided inside `fileInput` attribute..

Comment: @PankajParkar could you plz give me a specific example? thanks

Comment: you should have `<input file-input="myFile" type="file" />` after the directive change event gets fired you will get an value inside `$scope.myFile` inside controller..keep you code in link function

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks, file-input="files" was in view before, but it's still not working. Just updated my question. Please take a look at it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87330/discussion-between-hoangk-and-pankaj-parkar).

Answer (score 1):

it's working now. the problem was caused I used 2 nested directives :)
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I would use `scope` and `bindToController` attributes in the directive definition, like in the following snippet from [this blog](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html):

```
app.directive('someDirective', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      name: '='
    },
    controller: function () {
      this.name = 'Pascal';
    },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    template: '<div>{{ctrl.name}}</div>'
  };
});
```

It requires use of the `controllerAs` syntax too, but you should be using that anyway as it is much more clear than passing $scope around everywhere and dealing with prototypical inheritance.  This is recommended in [John Papa's AngularJS Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)